# Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint 2016 - only wish to migrate single site collection - easiest method?

Tags: 2013, 2016, migration

Objective - Sharepoint 2013 (only specific content - 1 site) migrate to Sharepoint 2016 - only wish to migrate single site collection - easiest method?

Plan is to migrate for testing ahead of live cutover (so at this stage not keen to use DB attach method if possible)

New to company so no IT history with how previous sites setup etc
This seems to be far more complex than it should be, not that familiar with SP.
Have tried the DB backup however this contains multiple sites, many no longer active or valid and dating back to SP 2007 - so full of rubbish and non compatible items/features

Tried a granular backup of site, on SP2016 cannot restore this as does not see this file (copied locally, tried multiple file ext's))

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is to move the site collection you want to migrate into it's own content DB with the Move-spsite command.  Then use the DB attach method to migrate the site.  Another option would be to use a third party tool, like ShareGate or Metalogix Content Matrix to migrate the site collection.

Comment: Just to add , while migrating make sure both the environments are on the same patch level .Otherwise the migrated content database will not open and give a compatibility issue.